# Corba IOR decode

Tags: java, corba, jacorb, iiop

I know this IOR may contain multiple components.The typical IOR normally contains the IP address of the remote host, the number of the remote port on that the CORBA server is listening, a string defining the class of the remote object on which the methods will be invoked, and the object key that is used by the server ORB to identify the object.

Is it possible that when I decode an IOR it gives me HOST NAME instead of IP Address.?

that is, it resolves like Machine-abc.co.in instead of some IP Adress like 192.168.64.56

Comment: Sure, why not? Just as useful in most cases.

Comment: See https://github.com/DOCGroup/ATCD/tree/master/TAO/utils/catior for the source code of the TAO catior utility that decodes the IOR

Comment: You have to make sure the server puts its hostname into the IOR, else the client will never see it, see the answer for how to do this with JacORB. For TAO see the -ORBDottedDecimalAddress commandline option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this to use DNS names in IORs

`jacorb.dns.enable=on`

Also , refer http://jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=872